# sql query - select duplicates within a 12 hour period

Tags: sql, oracle

if i have data as follows

A | 01/01/2008 00:00:00

B | 01/01/2008 01:00:00

A | 01/01/2008 11:59:00

C | 02/01/2008 00:00:00

D | 02/01/2008 01:00:00

D | 02/01/2008 20:00:00

I want to only select the records whose identifiers (A, B, C or D) have occured twice within a 12 hour period. In this example above this would only be 'A'

Can anyone help please (this is for an Oracle data base)

Thanks

M

Comment: When you say "this would only be A", do you not mean "A and D"?

Comment: No: 20:00:00 is more than 12 hours after 01:00:00.

Comment: Also, when you say "a 12 hour period", does that mean a 12 hour period defined by the clock, or a 12 hour period that starts from the first occurrence? I.e., do 01/01/2008 23:00 and 02/01/2008 01:00 count?

Comment: @Joel: oops! Sorry -- I was reading 12 hours and thinking 24, for some reason...

Answer (score 7):

```
 Select Distinct A.Identifer  
  From Table A
    Join Table B --  EDIT to eliminate self Joins (to same row)
        On A.PrimKey <> B.PrimaryKey
           And A.Identifer = B.Identifer               
           -- EDIT to fix case where 2 at same time
           And A.OccurTime >=  B.OccurTime 
           And A.OccurTime < B.OccurTime + .5
```

and to implement question asked in comment, 
(Ignoring records which are on different days)

-- for SQL Server,

```
   Select Distinct A.Identifer  
    From Table A
      Join Table B 
        On A.PrimKey <> B.PrimaryKey
           And A.Identifer = B.Identifer
           -- EDIT to fix case where 2 at same time
           And A.OccurTime >= B.OccurTime  
           And A.OccurTime < B.OccurTime + .5
    Where DateDiff(day, A.OccurTime, B.OccurTime) = 0
```

-- or for oracle...

```
 Select Distinct A.Identifer  
    From Table A
      Join Table B 
        On A.PrimKey <> B.PrimaryKey
           And A.Identifer = B.Identifer
           -- EDIT to fix case where 2 at same time
           And A.OccurTime >= B.OccurTime  
           And A.OccurTime < B.OccurTime + .5
 Where Trunc(A.OccurTime) = Trunc(B.OccurTime)
```

Comment: To avoid returning each duplicate set twice, add:  AND A.OccurTime > B.OccurTime

Comment: That will also let you do a simple > rather than a BETWEEN

Comment: I just changed it to between 0 and .5  - should do the same

Comment: It appears that your query is currently going to return every row because the same row in A & B will have the same identifier and the difference in OccurTime will always be 0.  So you probably want to throw an a.ROWID != b.ROWID in there.

Comment: If the combination of identifier and occurTime is unique, Joel's suggestion of A.OccurTime > B.OccurTime would also work

Comment: thansk for that that exactly what i needed. can i ask for one more thing how can i make it so that if after 12 hours we are into the next day dont return that record.
A | 01/01/2008 23:00:00
A | 02/01/2008 01:00:00

would not be selected

Comment: Add AND TRUNC(A.OccurTime) = TRUNC(B.OccurTime)

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the date column is unique, or unique for a given identifier? Two instances of A at time T would not satisfy the A.time > B.Time and fall through. So long as the data has a unique key, this is fine.

Comment: trunc is not necessary and does not work for times crossing day boundaries still satisfied by the 12hr window.

Along similiar lines SQLServers DATEDIFF is also wrong as it does not count the time between dates but rather the number of day boundaries crossed.

The greater or equal to should be greater than.  Ideally you would use a sequence or internal ROWID in the data to account for any possibility of multiple records being produced at the same time.  As it is now /w or without the results are ambiguous for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select    
  A.Id
From    
  YourTable A 
Where    
  A.YourDateTime Between :StartDateTime and :EndDateTime 
Group By    
  A.Id
Having    
  COUNT(A.Id) = 2
```

Comment: "Having Count(A.Id) > 1" if there could be more than 2

Comment: He means to say in ANY 12 hour period... not one specific time frame

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked William's query but I would seriously consider using what he has over every other. Analytics are da bomb. Anytime you find yourself joining a table back to itself is virtually guaranteed to be an opportunity to use analytics and will out perform the query with one table referenced twice every time.

You'll be **amazed** how much faster the analytic solution will be.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT identifier
  FROM table_name outer
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM table_name inner
                WHERE inner.identifier  = outer.identifier
                  AND inner.date_column BETWEEN outer.date_column AND outer.date_column + interval '12' hour
                  AND inner.rowid != outer.rowid )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of your requirements, however this might give you some ideas about how to do what you need. For example you said exactly 2; what if there are 3 occurances? etc.

```
create table t (ident varchar2(16), occurance timestamp);

insert into t (ident, occurance) values ('a', to_date('20080101000000', 'yyyymmddhh24miss'));

insert into t (ident, occurance) values ('b', to_date('20080101010000', 'yyyymmddhh24miss'));

insert into t (ident, occurance) values ('a', to_date('20080101115900', 'yyyymmddhh24miss'));

insert into t (ident, occurance) values ('c', to_date('20080102000000', 'yyyymmddhh24miss'));

insert into t (ident, occurance) values ('d', to_date('20080102010000', 'yyyymmddhh24miss'));

insert into t (ident, occurance) values ('d', to_date('20080102200000', 'yyyymmddhh24miss'));

insert into t (ident, occurance) values ('d', to_date('20080103020000', 'yyyymmddhh24miss'));

select ident, occurance
from
(
select ident, occurance,
    lag(occurance) over (partition by ident order by occurance) previous, 
    lead(occurance) over (partition by ident order by occurance) next 
from t
)
where 
    ((occurance-previous<interval'12:00' hour to minute and extract(day from occurance) = extract(day from previous))
    or (next-occurance<interval'12:00' hour to minute and extract(day from occurance) = extract(day from next)))
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT namecol FROM tbl A
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 from tbl B
  WHERE b.namecol = a.namecol
  AND b.timestamp > a.timestamp
  AND b.timestamp - 0.5 <= a.timestamp )
```

Comment: Clever to include the b.timestamp > a.timestamp predicate to enable indexes. You should have written a note about it, though